# How to get Private IP of HDI cluster using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-rm-template

I have created template1 which will deploy HDI cluster and template2 which will deploy Azure VM seperately.

Now I want to get the Head-node Private IP from cluster and pass it to Azure VM template for processing using ARM template.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

Considering this is the object you are getting from HDcluster:

```
{
    "id": "xxx",
    "name": "xxx",
    "type": "Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters",
    "location": "East US",
    "etag": "xxx",
    "tags": null,
    "properties": {
        "clusterVersion": "3.5.1000.0",
        "osType": "Linux",
        "clusterDefinition": {
            "blueprint": "https://blueprints.azurehdinsight.net/spark-3.5.1000.0.9865375.json",
            "kind": "SPARK",
            "componentVersion": {
                "Spark": "1.6"
            }
        },
        "computeProfile": {
            "roles": [
                {
                    "name": "headnode",
                    "targetInstanceCount": 2,
                    "hardwareProfile": {
                        "vmSize": "ExtraLarge"
                    },
                    "osProfile": {
                        "linuxOperatingSystemProfile": {
                            "username": "sshuser"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "workernode",
                    "targetInstanceCount": 1,
                    "hardwareProfile": {
                        "vmSize": "Large"
                    },
                    "osProfile": {
                        "linuxOperatingSystemProfile": {
                            "username": "sshuser"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "zookeepernode",
                    "targetInstanceCount": 3,
                    "hardwareProfile": {
                        "vmSize": "Medium"
                    },
                    "osProfile": {
                        "linuxOperatingSystemProfile": {
                            "username": "sshuser"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
        "clusterState": "Running",
        "createdDate": "2017-04-11T09:07:44.68",
        "quotaInfo": {
            "coresUsed": 20
        },
        "connectivityEndpoints": [
            {
                "name": "SSH",
                "protocol": "TCP",
                "location": "xxx.azurehdinsight.net",
                "port": 22
            },
            {
                "name": "HTTPS",
                "protocol": "TCP",
                "location": "xxx.azurehdinsight.net",
                "port": 443
            }
        ],
        "tier": "standard"
    }
}
```

I'm guessing this is the best output you can get, so you can use something like:

```
"outputs": {
    "test": {
        "type": "Object",
        "value": "[reference(parameters('clusterName'),'2015-03-01-preview').connectivityEndpoints[0].location]"
    }
}
```

This will get you an output of `xxx.azurehdinsight.net`

And you can either create a new deployment with this data or (just like I said) add RHEL VM to the same template and make it `dependOn` on the HDCluster deployment and reference the same thing as an input to VMextension.

Comment: 1. I get xxx.azurehdinsight.net as output. But I want to get internal IP. Is there a way to get it.  2. What you meant by create a new deployment after getting IP ? 3. Can I use linked template for VM? 4. To test this, I need to create cluster in which takes 20 minutes, Is there any simpler way to test this which takes less time?

Comment: 1. this is what you get. 2. Creating a new deployment means creating a new deployment. 3. you can, it doesn't matter linked template or just deploy it in the same template or just create another deployment. 4. No.

Comment: 3. how can we pass or use cluster IP in VM template?

Comment: the answer states that, use the same reference as an input to the scrip extension

Comment: I am going to use linked template with template, parameter files in json format. Will this work "[reference('linkedTemplate').outputs.test]" in VM template?

Comment: `"[reference('linkedTemplate').outputs.test.value]"`, but they have to be in the same parent template

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141423/discussion-between-karan-and-4c74356b41).

Comment: I have to use HDI template and VM template in same file. It means I can't use linkedtemplate. Right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141423/discussion-between-karan-and-4c74356b41)